# How to handle concurrency in online collaborative documents?

Tags: networking, concurrency

How can online collaborative documents solve the situation where two users modify a cell at the same time because of network problems, what technology is needed to solve this? What are the clear and known solutions?

By adding optimistic or pessimistic locks? How to solve it amicably?I'm more concerned with back-end processing solutions